# How to set proxy using node js

Tags: docusignapi

I want to upload documents on docusign using nodejs. But I am behind corporate proxy. I want to set proxy so that I can go outside the network. Can anyone please tell me how to do the same. If anyone have some code sample

Answer (score 0):

add the proxy servers as first line to your script
process.env.http_proxy ='http://hostname:port';
process.env.https_proxy ='http://hostname:port';

This works for standard node request methods. But it will not work when you are using the docusign-esign npm module

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

npm config set proxy `http://<username>:<password>@<proxyServerAddress>:<port>`

npm config set https-proxy `http://<username>:<password>@<proxyServerAddress>:<port>`